# How to find the last local maximum of a pandas time series?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, series

Given the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 7], ['d', 4], ['e', 1], ['f', 2], ['g', 9], ['h', 4], ['i', 0]])
```

is there a better way to find the last local maximum ('g') instead of iterating row by row in reverse and searching for previous row greater than current?

this is what I'm using at the moment, there has to be something more efficient:

```
df.columns = ['x', 'y']

first = True
prev_val = None
prev_row = None

for index, row in df[::-1].iterrows():
    if first:
        prev_val = row['y']
        prev_row = row['x']
        first = False
    else:    
        if row['y'] >= prev_val:
            prev_val = row['y']
            prev_row = row['x']
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In general*, you should try and avoid manual loops, especially with `iterrows`. One exception is `numba`, which performs iteration efficiently at a lower level:

```
from numba import jit

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 9], ['d', 4], ['e', 1],
                   ['f', 2], ['g', 7], ['h', 4], ['i', 0]])

@jit(nopython=True)
def local_max_idx(A):
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if A[-(i+1)] < A[-i]:
            return -i

res = df[0].iat[local_max_idx(df[1].values)]  # 'g'
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
n = 1000000
df = pd.Series([0] + list(range(n, 0, -1))).to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = [0, 1]

@jit(nopython=True)
def local_max_idx(A):
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if A[-(i+1)] < A[-i]:
            return -i

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

%timeit df.iat[argrelextrema(df[1].values, np.greater)[0][-1], 0]  # 46.1 ms per loop
%timeit df[0].iat[local_max_idx(df[1].values)]                     # 1.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: ...if not exist vectorized solution, do you think `argrelextrema` is not possible use here?

Comment: @jezrael, I added some performance benchmarking ,`scipy` for some reason seems slow when the local maximum is near the start of the series.

Comment: maybe because return all local max values

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scipy.signal.argrelextrema`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html):

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

a = df.iat[argrelextrema(df[1].values, np.greater)[0][-1], 0]
print (a)
g
```