# Find the last highest value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using a Pandas dataframe and I need to find the last highest value from a column.

For example, if this is my dataframe, I want to start at the last row and work up until I have the highest number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [102, 97, 94, 90, 90, 103, 90, 101, 62, 90, 90, 90]})
```

In this case it should stop and return 101. As the value before it was 90.

Any ideas?

I tried this but it just returns the highest of all rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [102, 97, 94, 90, 90, 90, 90, 101, 62, 90, 90, 90]})


def g(df):
    #return df.nlargest(1, 'col1')
    return df.iloc[::-1].col1.head(1).iloc[0]

result = g(df.copy())
print(result)
```

Comment: "In this case it should stop and return 101. As the value before it was 90." I can't understand. I think it should stop and return 90, because the value before that was 62. Why is that wrong? I also can't understand what "start at the last row and work up" should mean, nor why it should have anything to do with finding the right answer.

Comment: (@KarlKnechtel opinion) ++. I'm trying to figure out how to help, but your question is very confusing. Can you please explain it again, maybe using another approach?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the last local maximum in the column.  For that, you can adapt this answer [How to find the last local maximum of a pandas time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537299/how-to-find-the-last-local-maximum-of-a-pandas-time-series)

Answer (score -1):

Your current approach is just returning the first value of the reversed dataframe because you're using .head(1), which returns the first N rows.

check this one

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [102, 97, 94, 90, 90, 103, 90, 101, 62, 90, 
90, 90]})

def g(df):
   col1_reversed = df['col1'][::-1]   # This will reverse the order
   for i in range(1, len(col1_reversed)):
      if col1_reversed.iloc[i] > col1_reversed.iloc[i-1]:
          return col1_reversed.iloc[i]
   return None

result = g(df)
print(result)
```